# validation while editing form in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in angularjs  when we Edit from information,
if the user does not change any filed value then i want to disable the update button.
and if user changes any one filed also it should enable to update the information
place give me any way to do this

Comment: have you tried using a watch on all the fields to trigger changing the button's active state?

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation,  codepen link http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI

Comment: Show us what you coded so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a watch on all the fields is one way to go, or simply add the **ngInputModified** library to your app. 
To check if something has changed simply access myFrom.$dirty;

I also implement the setModifiedClassName('my-changed') to change the field backgrounds to another colour, very visual and effective

https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-disabled` in Angularjs.

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

What you have to do is to check if your fields are empty or not, and if they are empty, then your button is disabled. Using a boolean should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
<form name="regForm">
                <input type="text" name="xyz" ng-model="xyz"/><br>
                <input type="button" value="Click" ng-disabled="xyz == '' || !regForm.$dirty" />
            </form>
```